# How to update_site_option for specific site within network?

Tags: multisite, options

I would like to add or update site options (like those shown in the screenshot) using [update_site_option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_site_option/), but I have no idea (1) how to choose the correct site by its id? And where do I find the available (2) slugs for the options array?

[image: site options]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`update_site_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_site_option/) updates an option that's set for the entire network. If you're trying to update a specific site's option, eg `blogname`, you'll need to do [`update_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/]) instead.

If you're not sure of a site's ID, you can get its details using the site's slug with [`get_blog_details()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_blog_details/).

For example, if I wanted to change the `admin_email` and `some_other_option` options of the site at example.com/site-3:

```
$site_object = get_blog_details( 'site-3' );
if ( ! empty( $site_object ) ) {
    switch_to_blog( $site_object->blog_id );
    update_option( 'admin_email', 'admin@example.com' );
    update_option( 'some_other_option', 'Some Other Option Value' );
    restore_current_blog();
}
```

The confusion arises because when WordPress Multisite was initially developed, the terminology spoke of a **site** of **blogs**; later, though, it was updated to be a **network** of **sites**. The original terms still exist in function names like `update_site_option()` and `switch_to_blog()`.

### References

- [`update_site_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_site_option/)
- [`update_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/])
- [`get_blog_details()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_blog_details/)
- [`switch_to_blog()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_blog/)
- [`restore_current_blog()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/restore_current_blog/)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! That helped a lot! Any idea if there is a source where I can find the correct slugs for "some_other_option"? THANKS!

Comment: Guess this one helps me: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option. Over and out.

Comment: Note that the options in that list are some commons ones, some of them used by default by WordPress. Other developers can put just about anything into a site's options table. If you're using [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/), you can get the list using `wp option list`, or you can peek at the `option_name` column in a given site's `*_options` DB table.

Comment: Thank you very much, Pat!